# Old cartoon where a boy with a skeleton friend in a baseball cap battles monsters

Tags: identify-this-movie, identify-this-tv-show, science-fiction

Ok, I know this is a longshot, but I hope that somebody out there is able to help me. What I want to know is if anybody has ever heard of this. It is either a TV show or movie that I'm about to describe.

Okay, so I remember a long time ago I had this VHS tape (I'm guessing it's VHS)  and I don’t remember if it was a movie or TV show, but it was a cartoon. It was like one of those monster battle type TV shows, like Yu Gi Oh or Bakugan, something like that, but I'm guessing wasn’t too well known because I can't find it anywhere.

Okay, so all I remember from watching it is in the beginning there was a kid and he was at a school and walking down a dark hallway all alone, there were a bunch of doors, he went through one and it was like a portal that took him to another dimension or world.

In that place there was a bunch of monsters that were like his friends. 
(I think that when he got to the other world, he ended up right next to the gates of a cemetery or somewhere similar).
There was one monster who was a skeleton boy that wore a red baseball cap backwards was the boys best friend. 
While the boy was in this other world, he would go with his group of monster friends to a battle arena and duel.

At one point I think he was battling this big green gooey monster that I think was like a booger monster or something, and I remember the monster running at the boy while puckering its lips and making kissing noises and saying “give me a kiss!” or something like that. That’s all I remember.

I’m remembering all of this from a really long time ago, and who knows, I could have made this up, it could have been a dream, but I'm pretty certain that it's not. If anybody knows what I'm talking about, please tell me the name of it so I can possibly watch it again.

Comment: Are there any other external details you can give? Approximately how long was "a long time ago"? When you compare it to Yu Gi Oh and such things, does this alos apply to the style, i.e. was it an anime or a more Western kind of animation? You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title.

Comment: Made me think of "Might Max".

Answer (score 4):

Your description sounds a little like a 1980's cartoon called *Mighty Max*. It is about a boy that finds a magic hat that has the power to open a portal to another dimension. There, he encounters several strange creatures. The hat is red with a yellow 'M' on the front.

[Mighty Max on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mighty_Max_(TV_series))

> The series follows Max, an adventurous preteen boy who receives in the mail a small statue of a fowl, inscribed with Egyptian hieroglyphs whereof the translation states: "You have been chosen to be the cap-bearer. Go to the mini-mart and wait for a sign, Mighty Max". Shocked by the message, Max drops the statue, shattering it and revealing a red baseball cap emblazoned with a yellow "M", which he dons.

Mighty Max
[image: Mighty Max]

Comment: What Jason said. It's Mighty Max. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7VSBkq0n1Ks